# Why does reading a test resource with ':' in filename result in a NPE?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, url, uri

I am trying to determine how to read a file from resources with the special character `:` in it's name. I am traversing the directory in my main code which returns File listings that I use to ingest the file without issue.

In my unit test doing something as simple as:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/filename:containing.character")
```

returns a `java.lang.NullPointerException` due to the presence of the `:`, presumably because it thinks it is a protocol. What is the work around for this? I cannot rename the file as the filename encodes some information I am looking to test in this case.

Comment: Have you tried backslash `\\`?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Escaping via "\" will not work. Ask the compiler ;) - It will give you an `illegal escape character` complaint.

Comment: so u just double backslash that it escaped in java code and gives you a string with just one and it might get you escaping in file resolving.
But as I see in @MWiesner answer - it probably wouldn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Special characters for referencing resources

Quoting from the **IETF RFC 2396** specification by T. Berners-Lee et al., accessible from here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

> 2.2. Reserved Characters

> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
> special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
> their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
> purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
> reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
> forming the URI.
>
> ```
>   reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```

and

3. URI Syntactic Components

> The URI syntax is dependent upon the scheme.  In general, absolute
> URI are written as follows:
>
> ```
>   <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
> ```

### Consequence

*Java's* implementation of the `URL` class ([8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), [11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html), [14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html)) is compliant with the IETF RFC 2396 specification document. Therefore, references to resources should/must not contain any colon `:` symbol.

This will result in a `MalformedURLException` when parsed with your input `filename:containing.character` (see OpenJDK implementation of [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html), line 652). Next, this will result in a `null` value in URLClassPath (line 1254) as the previous instance of `MalformedURLException` is not thrown yet "converted" to a "non successful" response to `this.getClass().getResource(..)` call.

### Conclusion

1. Avoid colon (`:`) symbols in your filenames *OR*
2. Rename affected files before processing them as "resources" via URLs in Java.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MWiesner answer.

What we can do about if we already have files like that?

You can specify by parameter the folder in which those files are contained. And then traverse the list of children and find the desired file by simple name comparison.

Comment: Thanks, this is how I get to the files in production code so I will use a similar method for these test cases.